# Выборка данных из таблицы за определенное время по полю в секундах

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно получить все записи за последний месяц.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM users 
WHERE tc_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Но дело в том, что `tc_date` - поле в секундах.
Как его перевести в дату, чтобы работало корректно?

Comment: имеется ввиду [unix-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте

```sql
SELECT count(*) as c 
FROM users 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tc_date) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

из комментарий, обратное решение

```sql
SELECT count(*) as c 
FROM users 
WHERE tc_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

**еще лучший вариант**

```sql
SELECT count(*) as c 
FROM users 
WHERE tc_date >= CURRENT_MILLISEC/1000 + 30 * 86400
```

CURRENT_MILLISEC - текущая миллисекунда

30 - дней

86400 - секунд в сутке

Comment: Не удачное решение. Вы же статическое значение DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) сравниваете со значением функции от табличного tc_date. Т.е. придется перебирать все значения таблицы и расчитывать значение расчета FROM_UNIXTIME(tc_date). Необходимо противоположное решение. Статическое DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) привести к формату табличного tc_date. Тогда база сможет задействовать индексы и значительно быстрее вернуть ответ.

Comment: @Vitalts вы правы, первый метод будет работать медленее, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно переводить в дату не запись в базе, а наоборот входной параметр в секунды. Это будет корректнее с точки зрения производительности базы, в особенности это будет ощутимо, если по `tc_date` будет индекс. Т.е.:

```sql
SELECT count(*) as c 
FROM users 
WHERE tc_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```